Normalizer of product of subgroups
Let $G$ be a group and suppose that $H$ and $K$ are two subgroups of $G$.
The intersection of the normalizer of $H$ and the normalizer of $K$ is a subgroup of the normalizer of $HK$ (we do not assume that it is a subgroup of $G$).
Is it known that when the equality holds?

Here is a general negative answer, that provides you with a slew of counterexamples. Let $P \in Syl_p(G)$, and $N \unlhd G$, with $N \nsubseteq N_G(P)$. Then there is no equality. For $N_G(PN)=N_G(P)N$ (this is a well-known fact that can be proved with the help of the Frattini Argument) and $N_G(P) \cap N_G(N)=N_G(P) \cap G=N_G(P)$. Smallest example for this: $G=S_3$, $N=A_3$ and $P=\langle (12) \rangle$.
To my best knowledge there is no general criterium for general $H$ and $K$, to make your statement true.

Thank you very much

You are welcome and keep asking questions!

Normality of $H$ and $K$ is sufficient. Because it follows that $HK$ is then normal. So all three normalizers are (equal to) $G.$

But the poster explicitly said that we do not assume that $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Then how can we tall about it's normalizer?   @DerekHolt

For a subset $S$ of a group $G$, we define $N_G(S) = {g \in G : g^{-1}Sg=S }$.

@DerekHolt I see, so I forgot a basic bit of theory
